# Map View User Location Annotation Center is shifted by Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, mapkit, navigationbar

I'm not sure if this is a bug in MapKit or if I'm just doing something blatantly wrong but I've discovered an issue when trying to center the user location while also using a navigation bar from a navigation controller. My goal is to have a transparent navigation bar, which I achieve like this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

and to also have the user location annotation centered in the middle of the phone screen (note, not the middle of the view as it pertains to the bottom of the nav bar). I've tried everything from ignoring the scroll insets and setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property to all the different values. What I have right now looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, while the map view spans underneath the nav bar, the user location doesn't respect the true center and is shifted down. It should end up looking something like this:

[image]

Anyone else think this is fixable or should I just file a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a hack, but you could set the calendar's view.frame.origin.y to a negative value to offset the system's offset.

edit:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/centerOffset

MKAnnotationView class's

@property(nonatomic) CGPoint centerOffset

Discussion
By default, the center point of an annotation view is placed at the coordinate point of the associated annotation. You can use this property to reposition the annotation view as needed. This x and y offset values are measured in pixels. Positive offset values move the annotation view down and to the right, while negative values move it up and to the left.

Comment: ugh I feel so dirty though...well it's the best I have for now so here goes nothing!

Comment: Think I found it: MKAnnotationView class's @property(nonatomic) CGPoint centerOffset

Comment: I fixed it using this: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    UIView* view = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:self.mapView.userLocation];
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -(self.navigationController.navigationBar.height/2 + 10));
}